# How to accept strings containing escape characters python

Tags: python, string, escaping

If the user inputs a string containing an escape character (e.g. "Example\" or "C:\Users...), I want to accept it exactly as is. In other words, I'm trying to circumvent the Syntax error thrown when input like the above is processed.

I feel like it should be simple, but the answer eludes me. Any help?

EDIT: I'm on python 3

Comment: Most likely you're using `input` in Python 2.x, when you wanted to use `raw_input` (or Python 3.x).

Comment: Python 3, post edited to reflect that

Comment: I don't see how you can be getting a `SyntaxError` from an `input()` call in Python 3.  (Assuming that's what you're doing -- you didn't show any code describing what "is processed" means.)  Could you add `import sys` and `print(sys.version)` to your program to make sure you're using the Python you think you are?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `input()`; use `raw_input()` instead when accepting string input.

`input()` (on Python 2) tries to interpret the input string as Python, `raw_input()` does not try to interpret the text at all, including not trying to interpret `\` backslashes as escape sequences:

```
>>> raw_input('Please show me how this works: ')
Please show me how this works: This is \n how it works!
'This is \\n how it works!'
```

On Python 3, use just `input()` (which is Python 2's `raw_input()` renamed); unless you also use `eval()` it will *not* interpret escape codes:

```
>>> input('Please show me how this works: ')
Please show me how this works: This is \n how it works!
'This is \\n how it works!'
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified. I'm on python 3

Comment: @pipsqueaker117: Updated. Python 3 `input()` is the same function as the Python 2 `raw_input()` function.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using python 2.7 use raw_input() which accepts the string with special chars.

Sample program

```
$vi demo.py

str1=raw_input("Enter the file with full path : ")

print "Given Path is : ",str

save and quit from vi editor

Output 

$python demo.py

Enter the path :/home/ubuntu/deveops

Given path is  :  /home/ubuntu/deveops

$ python demo.py

Enter the path :\home\ubuntu\deveops

Given path is  :  \home\ubuntu\deveops
```

if you are using python3 use input() which accepts the string with special chars because python3 doesnot have raw_input() function

```
$vi demo1.py

 str1=input("Enter the file with full path : ")

 print ("Given Path is : ",str1)

save and quit from vi editor

Output

$python demo1.py

Enter the path :/home/ubuntu/deveops

Given path is  :  /home/ubuntu/deveops


$ python demo1.py

Enter the path :\home\ubuntu\deveops

Given path is  :  \home\ubuntu\deveops
```

Answer (score 0):

When processing the input, use the `eval()` function. Pass the input into the `eval()` function as an arguement.
For example:
PYTHON 3

```py
x=input()
x=eval(x)
```

Or

```py
x = eval ( input() )
```

```
input the following value:
\N{superscript two}

print ( x )
```

**output**:
`²`